# Double variable format

Tags: android

I have a the next line :

```
String.format("%10.6f",transform);
```

I use `String.format` to force the value to be shown with 6 decimals and not with `E`.

But when `transform` equals to `0.040000` I want to have `0.04` as result. And for `0.000006` I want to have `0.000006`.

Comment: Check my answer...if you want to format string

Answer (score 2):

Use NumberFormat instead of String.format():

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(6);
nf.format(yourNumber);
```